# How Prototypal inheritance works in reverse order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

As you can see below is my code. I have created two objects halogen and balloon and given halogen property of sing and balloon property of read. I am calling halogen.read() it is getting read property but halogen is prototype for balloon but balloon is not prototype of halogen. How js is working under the hood??

```js
const halogen = {
  sing: function() {
    console.log('I can sing');
  }
}

const balloon = new Object(halogen);

balloon.read = function() {
  console.log('I can read');
}

halogen.read();
```

Comment: The `new Object` call basically doesn't do anything, it's the same as `balloon = halogen`. There's no prototype involved.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the `Object` constructor with an argument that isn't `null` or `undefined`, it doesn't create a new object (not even when you use `new`, surprisingly; [spec link](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object-value)), it just converts the argument to object if it isn't already an object and returns it. Since `halogen` already refers to an object, there's no conversion required and you're basically doing `balloon = halogen` and they both end up referring to the **same** object.

You probably meant to use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), which creates a new object and assigns the object argument you provide as the new object's prototype:

```js
const halogen = {
    sing: function() {
        console.log("I can sing");
    },
};

const balloon = Object.create(halogen);

balloon.read = function() {
    console.log("I can read");
};

console.log(typeof halogen.read); // undefined
console.log(typeof balloon.read); // function
console.log(typeof balloon.sing); // function
```